# Spring boot, how to insert a new record with in a table with an EmbeddedId

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new to `Spring-boot` but kind of familiar with `JPA`. I have a project I am working on, I already have my `database` set up and generated my models from my database. I have worked on at least 4 `JPA` projects and this is the first time I have come accross `@EmbeddedId`.

I have a table `Passenger` that looks like

```
public class Passenger implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EmbeddedId
protected PassengerPK passengerPK;
@Size(max = 13)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_uuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private User user;
@Column(name = "date_created")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateCreated;
....
}
```

And my generated `passengerPK`

```
@Embeddable
public class PassengerPK implements Serializable {
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
@Column(name = "uuid")
private String uuid;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
@Column(name = "user_uuid")
private String userUuid;

public PassengerPK() {
}
...
}
```

Without an `@EmbeddedId` in `JPA` I would add a new record to the `Passenger` table by first `initializing` and saving a user

```
final User user = new User();
user.setUuid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
user.setFname(passengerDto.getFirstName());
user.setLname(passengerDto.getLastName());
user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(passengerDto.getPassword()));
user.setEmail(passengerDto.getEmail());
user.setPhone(passengerDto.getPhone());
user.setDateCreated(new Date());

User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
```

Then passing that user to my new `Passenger` like

```
  final Passenger passenger = new Passenger();
  passenger.setUuid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
  passenger.setUser(savedUser);
  passenger.setDateCreated(new Date());
  Passenger savedPassenger = passengerRepository.save(passenger);

But this fails, I get an error that `user_uuid` is null
```

Then I change try something like

```
final Passenger passenger = new Passenger();
PassengerPK passengerPK = new PassengerPK();
passengerPK.setUuid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
passengerPK.setUserUuid(savedUser.getUuid());
passenger.setPassengerPK(passengerPK);
passenger.setDateCreated(new Date());
Passenger savedPassenger = passengerRepository.save(passenger);
```

And I get the error `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydatabase`.`passenger`, CONSTRAINT`fk_passenger_user1`FOREIGN KEY (`user_uuid`) REFERENCES`user`(`uuid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)`
Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: In the last example somehow you've lost `passenger.setUser(savedUser);` If you still have this `private User user;` column on `Passenger ` class you need to fill it in too.

Comment: Hi i am struggling the word using new, i want to test a case similar to you, but using new will contradict the spring life cycle and result in this.passengerRepository is null,

how can you handle this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my `user` table storage engine was `myISAM` instead of `innoDB` like the rest of my tables. I changed it to `innoDB` and my code worked.